# kv Language id linked with another class Object as ObjectProperty kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to update a label text from another class using its update method in Clock but I couldn't understand why its not updating the label properly .I have a sample code below :

```
gui_v9 = '''
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock


<Level_1>:
    on_enter: self.EnterLevel_1()

<ScoreBar>:
    time_Label: timelabel
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        cols: 1
        size: root.size
        #Space away from border
        padding: 2
        spacing: 10
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 204/255.0, 204/255.0, 0/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text: 'Score'
            size_hint: .5, .5
        Label:
            text: "Level 1"
        Label:
            text: "Time :"
            id: timelabel
        Button:
            text: 'Mute'
'''

class ScoreBar(Widget):
    time_Label = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScoreBar, self).__init__()


class Level_1(Screen,Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level_1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=2,spacing=(10),padding=10)

    def EnterLevel_1(self):
        print "Hi This is EnterLevel_1 . Level One Gui work area  "
        scoreBar = ScoreBar()
        Field = tama(speed=3)
        self.layout.add_widget(Field)
        self.layout.add_widget(scoreBar)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        Clock.schedule_interval(Field.update, 10.0/100)
#Field
class tama(Widget):
    def __init__(self, speed=1 ):
        super(tama, self).__init__()
        self.speed = speed
        self.id = "Field"
        self.size = (800,600)
        self.Extra = 200
        print ScoreBar().time_Label.text

    def update(self,dt):
        print ScoreBar().time_Label.text
        ScoreBar().time_Label.text ="cdfdfd"

# Create the screen manager
Builder.load_string(gui_v9)
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Level_1(name='level_1'))

class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Comment: "Not updating it properly" would suggest it is updating it "somehow", but wrong? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have lines like

```
print ScoreBar().time_Label.text
```

This doesn't tell you anything about the existing ScoreBar, it makes a new one and returns information about that.

From the `tama`, you could refer to `self.parent.children[1]` to access the one you actually originally added, or devise another way to access the reference.

Comment: it works when i specify self.parent.children[1] or self.parent.children[0] but is there any way where i can do something like if self.parent.children[1] = <WidgetName> then do this .. I mean is there any way to get children by ids i.e. for child in self.parent.children ... then find particuar child ?